# passing HTTP data from grandparent to child in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

i have a grandparent component that a service for Observable response of HTTP get request.
i need those results to be passed to 2 child components , load to a table (if there's results) and only then the child component should be render.
how can i achive that? i guess a service will be the right way to go but i need the results to be available before the child components view rendering, so maybe there's a component lifecycle hook involved it the solution as well.
i tried transfering the data using dependency injection on the grandparent but the child was already rendered with no data.
i also tried a bit with services but was unable to achive the result i want.
i'm using Angular 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used EventEmitter on the service and subscribe to it by the child component.
that solved it and handle the dynamic data loading for me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can conditionally (with *ngIf) show/hide your child components. For condition statement you can check whether or not your Result object is initialized.